# Found a node with ID

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have an xml flow wit h this structure :

```
<TagNames>
  <TagName id="A1">some text...</TagName>
  <TagName id="A2">some text...</TagName>
  <TagName id="An">some text...</TagName>
</TagNames>
```

What's the best way to get only one node by 'id' without looping the entire file ?
Linq to Sql, Xpath... I am using C#

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using XPath; the syntax is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp.  If you get stuck, post some code & we can help further.  At the moment, it just looks like you want us to write some code for you.  If that's the case, email me for my rate :-)

Comment: code seems to be easy to write :) Just need to know if behind Xpath the engine do a loop. Or if linqTo Sql is better to solve this problem on large xml file. Thanks for your comment but I don't need a rating for my question ;)

Comment: I'm curious: why does it matter what the implementation is, provided it's sufficiently fast for your application?

Comment: In fact question was about perf on implementation. It is for web with high connection pool. Maybe use a DB instead of xml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath this is immediate:

```
"/TagNames/TagName[@id='A1']"
```

You can use it with **XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode** of **System.Xml**:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("input.xml");

  XmlNode single_node;
  XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
  single_node = root.SelectSingleNode("/TagNames/TagName[@id='A1']");

  Console.WriteLine(single_node.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LinqToXml you can do:

```
var xml = @"<TagNames>   
  <TagName id=""A1"">some text...</TagName>  
  <TagName id=""A2"">some text...</TagName>   
  <TagName id=""An"">some text...</TagName> 
</TagNames>";

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var node = 
document
.Root //The root node
.Elements("TagName") //all elements called TagName under the root.
.Where(element => element.Attribute("id").Value == "A1") //Node with an attribute called Id with the value "A1".
.Single(); //Only return 1 element.
```